# Iterate through views in a layout and change typeface

Tags: android, layout, view, typeface

I'm wondering if there is a way to iterate through all the views in a layout and change the typeface of all the views which have text (i.e. TextView, CheckBox, EditText, etc).  I have a layout which I call setContentView() and was wondering if there is an easy way to do this.

I could go through and manually do it using findViewById() but I'd rather have an easy way to iterate through them all instead.

Thanks,
-clark-

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe this will get you started:

```
protected void changeFonts(ViewGroup root) {

        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/comicsans.ttf");

        for(int i = 0; i <root.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View v = root.getChildAt(i);
                if(v instanceof TextView ) {
                        ((TextView)v).setTypeface(tf);
                } else if(v instanceof Button) {
                        ((Button)v).setTypeface(tf);
                } else if(v instanceof EditText) {
                        ((EditText)v).setTypeface(tf);
                } else if(v instanceof ViewGroup) {
                        changeFonts((ViewGroup)v);
                }
        }

    }
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you!  I had a layout with nested layouts and I simply called changeFonts() recursively on those and it worked out great.

Comment: Excellent solution! This post also solves a similar problem and explains the recursive approach: [SO - Iterate through ViewGroup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484471/loop-through-all-childs-of-groupview)

Comment: clever code should be incremented immediately, last else if statement made recursive searching, +1

Comment: Button and EditText are subclasses of TextView so I do not think you would ever cast to Button or EditText.