# Android - updating a huge amount to textviews

Tags: java, android, performance, textview

I have approx 100 textviews in my view, which all shows a value specific to it's id. The value is being set from another class in the program.

I am looking for a good solution, how to program this, without stalling the program or flooding it with memory.

To set an ordinary text in a textview:

```
public void setSpecificTextView(string myString)
{
     TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     text.setText(myString);
}
```

But I would have like 100 set functions, and each function would need to retrieve a textView each time. Seems like bad programming.

Also thought about allocating the textviews as private attributes, but also seems messy. What about a list or arraylist of textviews? But how to know which item in the list/arraylist belongs to which method

But since the textviews have very specific names, how can I handle this the best way?

EDIT: All my textviews are put into different tableLayouts and TableRows

Comment: 100 textviews! do you really need all those. I don't think its good. You can use a listview and listview recycles views.

Comment: It is a view showing all kind of needed data, which also needs to be printed out. So all of them is importent

Comment: why not use a listview then?

Comment: or have a single textview and append new data to it. but having 100 textviews is not good. Need to change your design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `TextView`s are all in a common `ViewGroup` you could use the [`getChildCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildCount%28%29) and [`getChildAt()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29) to iterate through the `TextView`s and set each ones text, instead of finding each one using `findViewById`.

Something like this :

```
for(int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++){
    View child = parent.getChildAt(i); 
    if(child instanceof TextView){       
        # ... do something with the text view
    }              
}
```

Comment: The textviews are in differet ViewGroups, which are in other viewgroup and in the end they are all in a linearLayout

Comment: Well you can traverse the `ViewGroup` recursively as you need : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7484547/220710

Comment: Was something like this I was looking for yes. Didn't solve my problem, but I am pretty sure my problem is unsolveable and I need to refactor some code :)

Answer (score 0):

make array of textview like

```
 TextView[] textView = new TextView[]{R.id.textview1, ......},
```

Answer (score 0):

Use listview with your custom adapter, Adapters are easy to update.

Comment: I am working with TableLayouts and not ListView's. So I guess I can't really use custom adapter?

Answer (score 0):

From the thing I understand is that you can use a Hashmap to store your textviews. By doing this, you will be able to quickly get the required textview and make required updates. Is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

A listview will give you scrolling for free which it sounds like you are going to need and using onitemclicklistner instead of a ton of onclicklisteners so you can treat the textedit views as a group instead of individually. I think you should YouTube a guy named slidenerd.his android video number 80 something is great.sure he talks fast and has an accent but it sounds like what you need is a listview adapter or baseadapter if you have more complex needs check it out.

Comment: I am not using a listView. I am using TableLayout with TableRows and TextViews inside these TableRows

Comment: all I can say is you probably have onitem... properties associated with the table layout that you could handle if someone enters text then put it in array myarray[index]