# Stop delayed transition

Tags: android, android-transitions

[TransitionManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/TransitionManager.html) has the endTransitions method, but it exist only for >= api 23. Is there a way that stops pending or executing transition that started by beginDelayedTransition?

There is problem when transition is overlapped...

Answer (score 4):

Call `TransitionManager.endTransitions`. If your `minSdkVersion` is lower than 23, use the TransitionManager of androidx.transition.

Answer (score 0):

As long as [*Transitions Api*](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/overview.html) internally uses [`Animator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html)s, you can [loop on all children of a `ViewGroup` recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7484547/1083957) and perform [`clearAnimation()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#clearAnimation()) on each child, or directly perform [`clearAnimation()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#clearAnimation()) on a particular view you do not want to transition.

**Note**, if this was a flawless way to do things, then framework would already implemented it for APIs upto 1, which means that there are some caveats (that I'm no aware of). But as a workaround you may try this solution.

Comment: Why do you have such a feeling? I haven't tested it, but I assume it will work. Will test that.

Comment: I'v seen sources and clearAnimation() deals with Animation but not Animator as you said. That is why I think that won't work... I'm sorry.

Comment: The Transition’s API uses Animators and Views use Animations (part of a different package, as already mentioned. `clearAnimation()` is only valid for the view’s animations (not the transaction’s Animators) (so confusing! )